# install curl on ubuntu to use hirak/prestissimo with composer

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, composer-php

I try to installhirak/prestissimo packages because my composer is very very very slow. 
I use

```
composer global require hirak/prestissimo
```

But I got this error. I found another solution on StackOverflow but I still can't fix that.

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for hirak/prestissimo ^0.3.6 -> satisfiable by hirak/prestissimo[0.3.6].
    - hirak/prestissimo 0.3.6 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
```

Thanks you all !!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

curl doesnt stay in php.ini

for ubuntu you need install it from terminal

install it like this

`sudo apt-cache search php-curl`

```
 sudo apt-get install php(version of php you are using)-curl
```

Answer (score 1):

So far, it's cURL issue. You've to install cURL and enable it. 

`sudo apt-cache search php-curl` and get your version number from there. Install by typing `sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl`. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command `sudo apt-get install php5-intl`

After that run this `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

if this does not work please check your dependencies for the error. It can check using this..firstly type `sudo apt-get install php5` on terminal after that enter the `tab`..Then you can see the packages.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-bcmath
```